# Are there virus scanners for Windows that can be run without installation?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware

I wonder if there are virus scanners that can be run without installation.
It would be very practical.
Simply insert the USB pen drive and scan...

It would be good if the scanner also detects malware.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here. Apart from that several vendors support creating a boot disk for scanning the disk from outside the normal OS and the german computer magazin c't provides once a year a bootable CD/USB version with several commercial scanners on it. But note that without installation you cannot get some features like on-access scanning etc since these require the scanner to hook into the system.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want a recommandation. I want a complete list.

Comment: *"I want a complete list."* - this is both too broad and off-topic and such a "complete" list will be quickly out of date too. This site is neither a vendor support site nor a site which provides lists of products. This site is about specific security related problems instead and wanting a list of products with specific features is not actually a security problem. I've addressed the part of your question which is on-topic already in my comment: yes, there are such products but there are serious limitations in what they can do.

Comment: Of course there are. Some AV companies also provide online scanning services.

Answer (score 1):

[ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/) a popular open-source AV scanner has a portable app version available on [portableapps.com](https://portableapps.com/apps/security/clamwin_portable).  This should allow you to manually scan drives and files from the USB drive, but the always-on background scanner will not work as that requires installation.